# Message error when starting Struts2 app: Can't find bundle for base name , locale en_US

Tags: java, struts2, wildfly-10

I have a web app done with Struts2 and deployed in Wildfly 10.
I read these errors in log application file:

```
Can't find bundle for base name Myfile, locale en_US
```

I checked my war and inside there is `Myfile.properties`, it's the first time i read this error.

I found that this error is also in log file of Spring SAML of  ws spring-security-saml2-sample.war , I suppose cannot invoke aar in my axis2.war :"org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Can't find bundle for base name fileEnvAxis2, locale en_US" ....""HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]""

Comment: *Where* is `Myfile.properties`? How are you generating the war?

Comment: Which is the default locale configured to your application server?

Comment: Hi Dave, Myfile.properties is in the root of My.aar archive in my axis2.war.
In spring-security-saml2-sample.war there is another MyFile.properties in folder "\WEB-INF\classes\". thanks

Comment: Hi Roman, where is the default locale in my Wildfly 10 ? thanks